# How can I find out how many 2* champions are there on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

Not every champions has a 1*, 2*, 3*, 4* version. Every time I get a 2* champion it is a duplicate, which makes me believe I have collected them all. But there is no way I can know for sure without looking at a list of all 2* champions. Something that cannot be found in-game.

After reading through many outdated forum posts from Kabam and GameFAQs I decided to ask here.

How do I find out how many 2* champions are there on Marvel CoC? Is there a list in-game? Is there an official list?

Comment: look at the source code

Comment: @Aequitas I can't... copyrighted stuff I guess...

Comment: I could try to find it for you if what you ask for doesn't exist already somewhere on the net. Could you give me the name of a 2* champion?

Comment: [does this help?](http://heavy.com/games/2014/12/marvel-contest-of-champions-tips-cheats-ios-android-mobile-games/2/)

Comment: @Aequitas It's outdated. But thanks

Comment: [Meta question about validity of this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10889/can-i-ask-a-question-whose-answer-changes-regularly)

Comment: [Kabam forum proposal asking devs to add in-game list of owned/not owned champions](http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?573442-List-all-the-champions-owned-and-not-owned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today there are 37 2* champions. There is no way to find out that information in game. The best source so far where people are trying to maintain a fairly updated list would be Wikia.

[Marvel Contest of The Champions Wikia](http://marvel-contestofchampions.wikia.com/wiki/Tier)

They recently added a row with total number of champions. They do a very good job keeping it up to date.

There is also a [very nice open project on github](http://gabriel-hook.github.io/contest-of-champions/synergies.html?stars=2) where you can see a map with all the champions and their synergies.

---

I have requested on Kabam forum to add a filter option to show all available champions.

[Kabam forum proposal](http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?573442-List-all-the-champions-owned-and-not-owned)

Comment: This answer is deprecated of course... Since then they even added Dr Strange and Quake to the list... so... you just have to figure out by counting... I wish they would add a kind of Pokedex for MCoC

Answer (score 1):

As of December 6, 2018, these are the champs by number:

2* 93

3* 123

4* 126

5* 92

6* 37

Reference http://marvel-contestofchampions.wikia.com/wiki/Tier

Answer (score -2):

As of today I currently own 36 - 2Stars; however, there are at least 3 more in exist which brings my tally up to 39. It's true you can look at the code to see who the new Champs are they are going to release. For instance, although about 10-12 new characters have been introduce since July, they are at least 4 more coming. I'm not sure how you can verify if they will be a 2Star - 5Star or only 2/4 or 3/4 1 of 4?!?  Coming up after today's release of Luke Cage will be Groot, Thor (female version), Jessica Johnson, & at least 1 more version of Venom.